# Isotope некорректно "выкладывает" лэйаут

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет!

При первой загрузке страницы лэйаут выкладывается некорректно, "пропуская" padding-bottom элементов, соответственное поулчается, что элементы накладываются друг на друга.
А вот после обновления страницы все приходит в норму.

Тут код - https://jsfiddle.net/4rdh5L9b/ , но не уверен, что тут можно будет наблюдать эту проблему при обновлении страницы.

```js
$('.ir_texts').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.ir_texts_item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 279
  }
});
```

```css
.index_reviews .ir_texts {
  float: left;
  width: 558px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item {
  width: 279px;
  padding: 35px 30px 35px 40px;
  font-family: 'muller_light';
  color: #111111;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_rating {
  height: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_rating:after {
  clear: both;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: '';
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_rating span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_rating span.itr_rating_red {
  background: #cd2d5e;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_text {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_text b {
  font-family: 'muller_medium';
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_more {
  height: 14px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_more a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #4fe1ce;
  border-bottom: #4fe1ce solid 1px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_more a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item .irt_date {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.irt_c1 {
  background: #faeaf1;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.irt_c2 {
  background: #f9e5ed;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.irt_c3 {
  background: #fbedf3;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options {
  padding: 40px 0 35px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options .itr_options_write {
  height: 49px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options .itr_options_write a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 49px;
  line-height: 51px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'muller_light';
  text-align: center;
  background: #cd2d5e;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options .itr_options_more {
  height: 14px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options .itr_options_more a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #cd2d5e;
  border-bottom: #cd2d5e solid 1px;
}
.index_reviews .ir_texts .ir_texts_item.itr_options .itr_options_more a:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0.0/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="index_reviews">
  <div class="ir_texts">
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c1">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        Огромное спасибо!)))
        <br />Заказывали для милых дам из нашего коллектива на 8 марта. Всем очень понравились букеты!...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Павел, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        13:41:10 / 03-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c2">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        <b>Доставка цветов и кап кейков</b>
        <br />
        <br />Большое спасибо за отличный сервис! Доставка вовремя, курьер очень приветливый...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Полина, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        12:08:34 / 02-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c3">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        <b>Доставка</b>
        <br />
        <br />Спасибо огромное )))
        <br />В первые встречаю настолько организованных, пунктуальных сотрудников...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Павел, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        13:41:10 / 03-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item itr_options">
      <div class="itr_options_write">
        <a>Написать отзыв</a>
      </div>
      <div class="itr_options_more">
        <a>Посмотреть все отзывы</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c3">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        <b>Доставка</b>
        <br />
        <br />Спасибо огромное )))
        <br />В первые встречаю настолько организованных, пунктуальных сотрудников...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Павел, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        13:41:10 / 03-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c1">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        Огромное спасибо!)))
        <br />Заказывали для милых дам из нашего коллектива на 8 марта. Всем очень понравились букеты!...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Павел, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        13:41:10 / 03-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ir_texts_item irt_c2">
      <div class="irt_rating">
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span class="itr_rating_red"></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_text">
        <b>Доставка цветов и кап кейков</b>
        <br />
        <br />Большое спасибо за отличный сервис! Доставка вовремя, курьер очень приветливый...
      </div>
      <div class="irt_more">
        <a>Читать полностью</a>
      </div>
      <div class="irt_name">
        Полина, Москва
      </div>
      <div class="irt_date">
        12:08:34 / 02-03-2016
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Может быть, кто-то встречал такую проблему? Из-за чего это может быть? Как можно решить?